# Syntax error: Unexpected token { on executing a TS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following code in TypeScript:

```
import { Document, Schema, Model, model } from "mongoose";
import { IUser } from "../interfaces/IUser";

export interface IUserModel extends IUser, Document {
}

var UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String
});

export const User: Model<IUserModel> = model<IUserModel>("User", UserSchema);
```

Then I use it in a controller. When I compile my TS app (tsc app.ts) it compiles fine. Then when I type "node app.js" in the terminal I get this error:

```
..\BlocG\models\user.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Document, Schema, Model, model } from "mongoose";
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Business\Cevian\CevianPrep\BlocG\data\db.ts:26:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

What makes it even stranger is that I have such imports in the controller:

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { IUserModel } from '../models';
```

...and it compiles with no problem. I used to execute the logic without any problems.

Please note that the error is not pointed at the import keyword but rather the curly bracket.

Please help me with this issue! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are compiling to ES6 modules which your node.js does not understand.

Comment: @Bergi So what do I do in order to make it work?

Comment: Change target to `"target": "es5"` into your `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: @Gilsdav It is es5. Is it possible that the tsconfig isn't correctly linked with my project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out, the basic problem was that I was compiling like this:

```
tsc app
```

Instead of just writing

```
tsc
```

This caused my compilation types to mix with the js ones in the same folder.

Also, I had imports directly from [name].ts files, where I should've used file names only.

Answer (score -1):

> Then when I type "node app.js" in the terminal I get this error:

Change your tsconfig `module` option to be something that will work both in node (natively) and browser (using e.g. webpack):

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

Comment: But I do have that line in tsconfig.... I also tried to compile it with those options (tsc app.ts -m commonjs --target ES5), still the same error..